# SSRS Enable/Disable filter based on parameter Value

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008

I have a report parameter of boolean type. 
If the value is true, a filter needs to be applied to a dataset, and if false it should not filter.
Sounds simple, but can't figure out..
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your dataset query you can add logic like:

```
WHERE
(
   @MyBooleanParam = 1 AND <filter code>
)
OR
(
  @MyBooleanParam = 0
)
```

So if the parameter is True, then the filter logic is applied in the query, if the parameter is false then no filter is applied.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Nathan's but an alternative would be to set up your filter as normal but wrap the expression in an `IIf` function that short circuits the filter:

```
=iif(parameter!myboolean.value = 1, parameter!myfilter.value, fields!field_im_filtering.value)
```